# Why getting "segmentation fault" when sending 127 characters to a buffer with capacity of 128

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, buffer-overflow

I have the following code taken from [a binary exploitation exercises](https://exploit.education/phoenix/stack-five/):

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BANNER \
  "Welcome to " LEVELNAME ", brought to you by https://exploit.education"

char *gets(char *);

void start_level() {
  char buffer[128];
  gets(buffer);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  printf("%s\n", BANNER);
  start_level();
}
```

My question is regarding the way the buffer stores the information.
Our buffer has storage for 128 characters.

When I send 127 characters I am getting segmentation fault:

```bash
user@phoenix-amd64:/opt/phoenix/amd64$ python -c 'print("A"*127)'  | ./stack-five 
Welcome to phoenix/stack-five, brought to you by https://exploit.education
Segmentation fault
```

But if I send 126 characters, there is not error:

```
user@phoenix-amd64:/opt/phoenix/amd64$ python -c 'print("A"*126)'  | ./stack-five 
Welcome to phoenix/stack-five, brought to you by https://exploit.education
user@phoenix-amd64:
```

If the buffer has capacity of 128, and I sent it 127 characters, why it failed? It should have at least one more place no?

One thing I though is maybe after sending 127 characters, it adds the NULL terminator (`\x00`) but even if that happens, we have exactly 128 characters, so why it crash?

Comment: `gets()` appends a trailing `'\0'` to the passed array.   So, if you "send" `n` characters, `n + 1` characters are written.    If `n + 1` exceeds the array size, behaviour is undefined.

Comment: @Peter, if I send 127 characters it adds `'\0'` so we have 128 characters which is exact the capacity, why it still crash?

Comment: Does `python -c 'print("A"*126)'` append a new line?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica no

Comment: I suspect `gets(buffer);` is simply getting more than you think.  Try printing `strlen(buffer)` when you do `python -c 'print("A"*126)' `.

Comment: The default separator and end used by python `print` are both a space character.

Comment: E235, Aside, why use `gets()`? It has been dropped from the C library since C11 (12 years ago).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica it's an exercise for binary exploitation.

Comment: @E235 Even if this is an exercise, `gets()` is not part of up-to-date C standard library.  Using `gets()` can prevent you from learning the latest C.  Whomever is assigning such a task, offer them `"%[^\n]%*c"`.  It is a similar exploit in both old and current C. IMHO some prof needs to update their course.

Comment: I tried the code on my Mac, I don't get a segfault for 127, only for 128. Which makes sense because of the NULL terminator. 
What platform are you running this on? Try printing 130 bytes of memory at the address buffer to see what characters are in the last few bytes.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica you are right, but I think the idea is to learn about the basic of exploiting the stack and understand how it works. And also I want to finish these classic exercise and than search for a more updated course.

Comment: Side note: you return no value from value-returning `main()`. It's UB.

Comment: @E235 Whatever works for you.  Still suggest more up-to-date study.

Comment: @dimich No it is not UB.  `main()` is special.  "reaching the } that terminates the main function returns a value of 0."

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Yes, you are right. Since C99 it's equivalent to returning 0.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica noted, thanks. I will search for something more updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a buffer overflow between the '\n' that Python `print()` adds and the '\0' you need for the string that c adds:

```
[python3 -c 'print("A"*126)' | wc -c
127
```

I would fix that in Python with:

```
python3 -c "print('A'*126, end='')" | wc -c
126
```

`gets()` is unsafe so use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: thanks, it seems this was the problem.  It added new line + the null terminator created a buffer overflow.  
I know that `gets()` is unsafe, this is part of the exercise :)

Comment: @Allan, So [Does python -c 'print("A"*126)' append a new line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77504824/why-getting-segmentation-fault-when-sending-127-characters-to-a-buffer-with-ca?noredirect=1#comment136636758_77504824) does append a new line?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica `print()` always adds a newline (unless you overwrite it with the `end` argument).  Let me elaborate on that in the answer.

Comment: Yeah, or `fgets()` with a buffer smaller than the size provided.  There a valuable lesson in that case of using symbolic constants and/or `sizeof`.  Or `scanf()` with out a maximum field width.  In fact do both as it's super annoying that the size field are off by 1 between those two currently used functions.

Comment: It seems that it adds a new line, I checked it with by printing to a file `python3 -c "print('A'*10)" > mytest` and then use `xxd mytest` and received:  `4141 4141 4141 4141 4141 0a`

Comment: `od -a` or `od -c` is another option.  `od` is usually installed by default (on Debian it's part of coreutils) while `xxd` is an extra package to install.

Comment: python `print()` adds a new line, but `gets()` doesn't read the new line character. I still don't understand why OP get's a segfault. On my machine the code doesn't produce a segfault with 127

Comment: @hko Platform specific behavior of `gets()`?  There is nothing else fishy.

Comment: Yes, very possible.